# Проблема к присоединению к серверу c android приложения Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.andre.socketapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun Connect( view : View){
        val ip = "192.168.0.101"
        val port = 1111
        val message = "Hello from android "
        try {
            val socket = Socket(ip, port)
            val printWriter = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
            printWriter.write(message)
            printWriter.flush()
            printWriter.close()
            socket.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            textV.text=e.localizedMessage;//socket failed:EACCES (Permission denied)
        }
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку (функция Connect) исключение выводит ошибку "socket failed:EACCES (Permission denied)", в чём проблема и как исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас разрешение на интернет в манифесте не указано.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, по гуглил я на счёт манифеста и добавил следующие разрешения: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />, теперь исключение не выдаёт ошибку, а приложение просто закрывается

Comment: Если закрывается - значит крашится. Смотрите где в логах.

Comment: Теперь скорее всего `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, нельзя в UI потоке сетевые запросы делать. По этой теме уже много чего написано.